# Reload telerik grid after data update

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, telerik-grid

How can I reload/refresh a telerik data grid after data update? Is there an inbuilt telerik function which I can call in ajax success? If not, how best to refresh/reload a telerik grid?

jquery:

```
$("#SaveHours").click(function (e) {

    e.preventDefault();
    var link = '/Project/SaveHours';

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: link,
        data: { hours: $("#HoursWorked").val(),
            descType: $("#Description").val(),
            wrkType: $("#WorkType").val()
        },
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (result) {
            alert(result.message);
        },
        error: function (result) {
            alert("Failed");
        }
    });
```

The Grid is located in a partial view, Here is how I return the Partial:

```
 <%  Html.RenderAction("Hours"); %>
```

Here is my Controller Action:

```
[GridAction]
public ActionResult Hours()
{
    ViewData.Model = db.vwHours;
    return View();
}
```

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use telerik grid rebind method

```
$.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: link,
        data: { hours: $("#HoursWorked").val(),
            descType: $("#Description").val(),
            wrkType: $("#WorkType").val()
        },
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (result) {
            //rebind here
            var grid =  $("#MyGrid").data("tGrid");
            grid.dataBind(result.data)
        },
        error: function (result) {
            alert("Failed");
        }
    });
```

Comment: Still doesnt refresh the gird. Could it be the way I have the gird loaded? The grid is in a partial view and I am rendering the action that returns the partial view on the Master.

Comment: @user793468 Have you check your grid variable in firebug or other debugger?

Comment: Here is the error I get: Error: the requested URL did not return JSON

Comment: Here is How I got it to work -                                    
Adding this to success function:           $("#Hours").data("tGrid").dataBind(result.data);                    
and, adding this to my delete controller action:                    
return Json(new { data = project.vwHours });

Comment: @user793468 No problem just ask )